# Only find sub and super script in excel files and replace them with same unicode or symbols

Tags: excel, vba

We are teachers and have a lot of chemistry, Physics and Math MCQs in excel files with lot of formulas and equations. When we tried to import these MCQs into mySQL based database all subscripts and supercripts used in formulas lost and taken as normal character e.g, H2SO4, CO2, CH3 etc and makes our formulas and elements name nonsense. Is there any solution by which mySQL can import subscript and superscript as it is from excel? Or Is there any solution by which we can replace excel only subscript and superscript by symbols or unicode because mySQL can pick symbols and unicode as it is?
Rightnow we are replacing sub and super scripts with same type of symbols/unicode manually so that it can be remain the same after importing into the mysql for our web application.But it will take nearly two month to complete this hectic task.
We are taking help from this website https://unicode-table.com/en/#superscripts-and-subscripts
So please help us in this regards.

First I have tried to ask question that how can I import excel with sub and super scripts into mysql, my very first question in the community but got no answer

by use of your provided code/method/solution only sub and super scripts found into all excel files will replaced by same unicode/symbol character and then can be imported into mysql as it is and will be shown on the web same as present into the excel e.g, H₂O in excel --> H₂O on web (2 is unicode character)

Comment: How are you importing the data from excel to MySQL? also, if the data being imported to MySQL is losing its format, how is that affecting the formulas in excel? I suspect I didn't understand the question

Comment: Our application is built in PHP, we made an interface at admin level where select file from local PC and then import into mysql. You cannot import sub and super scripts from excel to any database which I know up to my knowledge. So we are going towards replacement in excel with unicode which can be imported to any sql as they are.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your data and the way in which you're transferring the data, it's very difficult to give you an answer. I suspect this is why you've received no responses to your posts.

I'd guess there's a decent chance that your Excel equations are simply formatted as sub- and super-script characters, so an option might be to do a Unicode conversion within Excel itself.

The code below should get you started - though, I'm sure you've already read that this site isn't a free code-writing service, so you'd need to amend it and/or expand it to suit your own needs. It basically creates a map of sub- and superscript characters to their Unicode equivalents and then converts any characters it can find in the map. It'll paint a character red if there's no match.

I suspect this will be the simplest way to go for you. Your other option would be to convert each item as you write it to the database, but without seeing your code I'm not able to produce a working example for you.

Good luck.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RunMe()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim map As Collection, unresolveds As Collection
    Dim i As Long
    Dim str As String
    Dim v As Variant

    'Create the map of sub- and superscripts.
    Set map = GetScriptsMap

    'Create the output sheet.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set ws = .Add(After:=.Item(.Count))
    End With

    'Iterate each cell in the range.
    For Each cell In Sheet1.UsedRange.Cells
        If cell.Characters.Count > 0 Then
            'Reset the collection of unresolved characters.
            Set unresolveds = New Collection
            'Iterate the text character by character.
            For i = 1 To cell.Characters.Count
                With cell.Characters(i, 1)
                    str = .Text
                    With .Font
                        'Check for sub- or superscript.
                        If .Subscript Or .Superscript Then
                            'Attempt a lookup of sub- or superscript characters.
                            'If the lookup fails, the str variable will hold its
                            'old .Text value.
                            On Error Resume Next
                            str = ChrW(map(str & IIf(.Subscript, "B", "P")))
                            'A failed lookup will return an error number,
                            'so add it to the collection of unresolved characters.
                            If Err.Number > 0 Then unresolveds.Add i
                            On Error GoTo 0
                        End If
                    End With
                End With
                'Build the output cell.
                With ws.Range(cell.Address)
                    .Value = .Value & str
                End With
            Next
            'Colour the unresolved characters red.
            For Each v In unresolveds
                ws.Range(cell.Address).Characters(v, 1).Font.Color = vbRed
            Next
        End If

    Next
End Sub

Private Function GetScriptsMap() As Collection
    Dim map As Collection

    Set map = New Collection

    'Superscript unicodes - key suffixed with 'P'
    map.Add &H2070, "0P"
    map.Add &H2071, "1P"
    map.Add &HB2, "2P"
    map.Add &HB3, "3P"
    map.Add &H2074, "4P"
    map.Add &H2075, "5P"
    map.Add &H2076, "6P"
    map.Add &H2077, "7P"
    map.Add &H2078, "8P"
    map.Add &H2079, "9P"
    map.Add &H207A, "+P"
    map.Add &H207B, "-P"
    map.Add &H207C, "=P"
    map.Add &H207D, "(P"
    map.Add &H207E, ")P"
    map.Add &H207F, "nP"
    'Subscript unicodes - key suffixed with 'B'
    map.Add &H2080, "0B"
    map.Add &H2081, "1B"
    map.Add &H2082, "2B"
    map.Add &H2083, "3B"
    map.Add &H2084, "4B"
    map.Add &H2085, "5B"
    map.Add &H2086, "6B"
    map.Add &H2087, "7B"
    map.Add &H2088, "8B"
    map.Add &H2089, "9B"
    map.Add &H208A, "+B"
    map.Add &H208B, "-B"
    map.Add &H208C, "=B"
    map.Add &H208D, "(B"
    map.Add &H208E, ")B"
    map.Add &H2090, "aB"
    map.Add &H2091, "eB"
    map.Add &H2092, "oB"
    map.Add &H2093, "xB"
    map.Add &H2094, ChrW(&H18F) & "B"
    map.Add &H2095, "hB"
    map.Add &H2096, "kB"
    map.Add &H2097, "lB"
    map.Add &H2098, "mB"
    map.Add &H2099, "nB"
    map.Add &H209A, "pB"
    map.Add &H209B, "sB"
    map.Add &H209C, "tB"

    Set GetScriptsMap = map
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Though @Ambie already presented a well constructed solution and also well explained the topics, but even then I just want share my details of trail and code in this regard. Here whatever Super & Subscript Unicode characters are to be tabled in blank sheet named ”ScriptMap” in a empty excel file.  I used decimal value of the columns 4,5 derived with `Hex2DEC` from the Hex Unicode value. The table is copied from some website (could not vouch authenticity) may be modified and / or added to one's finding.

```
Chars   Uni Sup Uni Sub Dec Sup Dec Sub
0   2070    2080    8304    8320
1   00B9    2081    185 8321
2   00B2    2082    178 8322
3   00B3    2083    179 8323
4   2074    2084    8308    8324
5   2075    2085    8309    8325
6   2076    2086    8310    8326
7   2077    2087    8311    8327
8   2078    2088    8312    8328
9   2079    2089    8313    8329
a   1d43    2090    7491    8336
b   1d47        7495    0
c   1d9c        7580    0
d   1d48        7496    0
e   1d49    2091    7497    8337
f   1da0        7584    0
g   1d4d        7501    0
h   02b0    2095    688 8341
i   2071    1d62    8305    7522
j   02b2    2c7c    690 11388
k   1d4f    2096    7503    8342
l   02e1    2097    737 8343
m   1d50    2098    7504    8344
n   207f    2099    8319    8345
o   1d52    2092    7506    8338
p   1d56    209a    7510    8346
q           0   0
r   02b3    1d63    691 7523
s   02e2    209b    738 8347
t   1d57    209c    7511    8348
u   1d58    1d64    7512    7524
v   1d5b    1d65    7515    7525
w   02b7        695 0
x   02e3    2093    739 8339
y   02b8        696 0
z           0   0
A   1d2c        7468    0
B   1d2e        7470    0
C           0   0
D   1d30        7472    0
E   1d31        7473    0
F           0   0
G   1d33        7475    0
H   1d34        7476    0
I   1d35        7477    0
J   1d36        7478    0
K   1d37        7479    0
L   1d38        7480    0
M   1d39        7481    0
N   1d3a        7482    0
O   1d3c        7484    0
P   1d3e        7486    0
Q           0   0
R   1d3f        7487    0
S           0   0
T   1d40        7488    0
U   1d41        7489    0
V   2c7d        11389   0
W   1d42        7490    0
+   207A    208A    8314    8330
-   207B    208B    8315    8331
=   207C    208C    8316    8332
(   207D    208D    8317    8333
)   207E    208E    8318    8334
```

As the project involves number of excel files, multiple files could be selected at the start of the execution of the code. It would loop through all the selected files, all the sheets and cells.
However I am delayed  as I am not satisfied with the speed / efficiency of the code.  I found It takes around 15 minutes ( in my old laptop)  to perform replacement of around 100 cells, each containing around 50 sub & superscript in a used range of around  100 X 26 cells containing text. At start I started with files with 100 X 26 cells each containing around 50 sub & superscript and had to abort trail in the middle of  execution. So the code may be not at all usable if the number of files and number of sub & superscript ( and used ranges ) are very large. Though I personally dont like keeping Calculation,  screenupdating & enableEvents off, that also could not speed it up significantly. Therefore *I invite further answers with boosted up speed / efficiency of similar operation.*

The code (to be added and to be executed from the empty file containing sheet "ScriptMap") :

```
Option Explicit
Sub ToUni()
Dim tm As Long
Dim Wb As Workbook, Ws As Worksheet, Rng As Range, Cel As Range
Dim Fname As Variant, Cha As Characters
Dim fl As FileDialog, ScrMap As Variant
Dim SupTxt As String
Dim i As Long, n As Long, UniNo As Long
tm = Timer
ScrMap = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ScriptMap").Range("A2:E65").Value 'modify to your requirement

'select files for conversion
Set fl = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fl
  .AllowMultiSelect = True
  .InitialFileName = "C:\Temp\"
  .Filters.Clear
  .Filters.Add "All Excel Files", "*.xls*"
  .Show
End With

If fl.SelectedItems.Count <= 0 Then Exit Sub

   For Each Fname In fl.SelectedItems
   Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(Fname)
      For Each Ws In Wb.Worksheets
      Debug.Print Ws.Name
      Set Rng = Ws.UsedRange
        For Each Cel In Rng.Cells
        Debug.Print Cel.Address(False, False)
        If VarType(Cel.Value) = vbString Then
                For i = 1 To Cel.Characters.Count
                If Cel.Characters(i, 1).Font.Superscript Or Cel.Characters(i).Font.Subscript Then
                SupTxt = Cel.Characters(i, 1).Text

                    'Find unicode value of the char from ScrMap if avialable
                    For n = LBound(ScrMap, 1) To UBound(ScrMap, 1)
                    UniNo = 0

                        If SupTxt = ScrMap(n, 1) Then
                        If Cel.Characters(i, 1).Font.Superscript Then UniNo = ScrMap(n, 4)
                        If Cel.Characters(i, 1).Font.Subscript Then UniNo = ScrMap(n, 5)
                        End If
                    If UniNo > 0 Then Exit For
                    Next n

                    If UniNo > 0 Then
                    Cel.Characters(i, 1).Text = ChrW(UniNo)
                    'Debug.Print i, SupTxt, UniNo
                    End If

                End If
            Next i
        End If

        Next Cel
      Rng.Font.Superscript = False
      Rng.Font.Subscript = False
      Next Ws

   Debug.Print Wb.Path & "\" & Wb.Name
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Wb.SaveAs Wb.Path & "\1converted_" & Wb.Name
   Wb.Close False
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   Next Fname
Debug.Print Timer - tm
End Sub
```

The code does not replace the original file but save changed file by adding some Prefix in the file name in the same directory.